# Too many uwsgi threads running

Tags: python, django, multithreading, nginx, uwsgi

Good morning,

I am new to webserver infrastructures and administration. I have the following issue with a webserver I try to mount, using nginx + uwsgi + django and python: with every refresh or request to the webpage that a user is doing, uwsgi creates 2-3 new threads that never terminate. After some days, I end up with more than 30000 threads and I have to reload uwsgi in order to maintain the performance of the webpage.

To check the number of threads I use the following command:
[ps - eLf | grep uwsgi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZOvI.png) (you can see the result attached).

My uwsgi configuration is the following:

```
[uwsgi]

vhost = true

socket = /tmp/mySocket.sock

master = true

processes = 4

max_request =  300

vacuum = true

die-on-term = true

close-on-exec = true

harakiri = 30

wsgi-file = /home/virtualEnv/server/wsgi.py

virtualenv = /home/virtualEnv

pythonpath = /home/virtualEnv/myServer

chdir=/home/virtualEnv/myServer

pidfile=/tmp/myFile.pid

daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi/uwsgi-@(exec://date +%%Y-%%m-%%d).log

log-reopen = true

chmod-socket = 664

gid = www-data

uid = www-data
```

My uwsgi.py file is the following:

```
import os
import sys

path = ‘/home/virtualEnv/myServer'
if path not in sys.path:
   sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myServer.settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And my /etc/init/uwsgi.conf file is:

```
description "uWSGI Emperor"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
exec uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals/ --wsgi-file /home/virtualEnv/server/wsgi.py
```

I have tried using uwsgi with and without threads, with and without --thunder-lock but nothing really changes.

**EDIT:**

After cleaning the uwsgi.ini file I continue having the same issue. The current configuration of the files is:

uwsgi.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /tmp/mySocket.sock
master = true
processes = 4
max_request =  3
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
close-on-exec = true
harakiri = 30
wsgi-file = /home/virtualEnv/server/wsgi.py
virtualenv = /home/virtualEnv
pythonpath = /home/virtualEnv/myServer
chdir=/home/virtualEnv/myServer
pidfile=/tmp/myFile.pid
logger = file:/var/log/uwsgi/uwsgi-@(exec://date +%%Y-%%m-%%d).log
log-reopen = true
chmod-socket = 664
gid = www-data
uid = www-data
```

uwsgi.conf

```
description "uWSGI Emperor"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
exec uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals/
```

nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 10000;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
events {
worker_connections 10000;
multi_accept on;
use epoll;
}

http {
server_tokens off;
resolver 8.8.8.8;
map $http_accept_language $lang {
default en;
~*en en;
~*pt pt;
~*fr fr;
~*it it;
~*es es;
~*ru ru;
~*ro ro;}
client_body_buffer_size 10K;
client_header_buffer_size 1k;
client_max_body_size 10m;
large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;
client_body_timeout 12;
client_header_timeout 12;
keepalive_requests 100;
send_timeout 10;
open_file_cache max=2500 inactive=20s;
open_file_cache_valid 30s;
open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
open_file_cache_errors on;
sendfile off;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 5000;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
charset UTF-8;
gzip on;
gzip_http_version 1.0;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_static on;
gzip_disable ""msie6"";
gzip_min_length 256;
gzip_comp_level 1;
gzip_buffers 4 32k;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}"
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem, were you able to find the solution?

Comment: I have not found a solution other than gracefully reloading the workers when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You're starting uWSGI emperor, so you shouldn't pass wsgi-file directly to it. Remove that parameter from your uwsgi.conf file.

When using emperor, you shouldn't daemonize your uWSGI instances, because emperor will loose connection to it, that probably causes spawning new instances on each request (emperor doesn't know that there are some instances, because they've daemonized so it spawns new one to handle requests). You should remove `daemonize` from your uWSGI configuration.

Also, using `vhost` when explicitly pointing to wsgi file shouldn't be done. If you don't know what this parameter does or don't think that you're need it, remove it.

After changes, your files should look like:

uwsgi.ini file:

```
[uwsgi]


socket = /tmp/mySocket.sock
master = true
processes = 4
max_request =  300
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
close-on-exec = true
harakiri = 30
wsgi-file = /home/virtualEnv/server/wsgi.py
virtualenv = /home/virtualEnv
pythonpath = /home/virtualEnv/myServer
chdir=/home/virtualEnv/myServer
pidfile=/tmp/myFile.pid
log-reopen = true
chmod-socket = 664

gid = www-data
uid = www-data
```

uwsgi.conf file:

```
description "uWSGI Emperor"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
exec uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals/
```

wsgi.py file won't change.

If you want to have logfile from your uwsgi server, use:

```
logger                  = file:/var/log/uwsgi/uwsgi-@(exec://date +%%Y-%%m-%%d).log
```

instead of `daemonize`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I have tried the configurations you suggested, but the problem seems to persist. The workers never seem to be reloaded. For example, if I set the max_request value to 5, shouldn't the workers be reloaded after having served 5 requests?

Comment: Please show your nginx config and uWSGI config after changes i've mentioned